# How to set built-in color scheme for gnome-terminal via CLI in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: command-line, gnome, 16.04, gnome-terminal, colors

I want to change the color scheme of gnome-terminal to the built-in scheme Rxvt. I know how to set the fore- and background color and 'use-theme-colors', with gsettings, but I just can't find the right key to set the scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As egmont mentioned in a comment,

> the color "scheme" (e.g. "rxvt") is not stored in the settings, it's the 16 individual colors that are stored. The color "scheme" is only a concept of the graphical profile editor.

#### 16.04

In the below commands, replace `$profile` with your profile ID, which you can get from

```
dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

If you have only one profile, you can create the variable:

```
profile="$(dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/ | sed 's./..')"
```

- **Tango**

  ```
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/$profile/palette "['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgb(204,0,0)', 'rgb(78,154,6)', 'rgb(196,160,0)', 'rgb(52,101,164)', 'rgb(117,80,123)', 'rgb(6,152,154)', 'rgb(211,215,207)', 'rgb(85,87,83)', 'rgb(239,41,41)', 'rgb(138,226,52)', 'rgb(252,233,79)', 'rgb(114,159,207)', 'rgb(173,127,168)', 'rgb(52,226,226)', 'rgb(238,238,236)']"
  ```
- **Linux console**

  ```
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/$profile/palette "['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgb(170,0,0)', 'rgb(0,170,0)', 'rgb(170,85,0)', 'rgb(0,0,170)', 'rgb(170,0,170)', 'rgb(0,170,170)', 'rgb(170,170,170)', 'rgb(85,85,85)', 'rgb(255,85,85)', 'rgb(85,255,85)', 'rgb(255,255,85)', 'rgb(85,85,255)', 'rgb(255,85,255)', 'rgb(85,255,255)', 'rgb(255,255,255)']"
  ```
- **XTerm**

  ```
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/$profile/palette "['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgb(205,0,0)', 'rgb(0,205,0)', 'rgb(205,205,0)', 'rgb(30,144,255)', 'rgb(205,0,205)', 'rgb(0,205,205)', 'rgb(229,229,229)', 'rgb(76,76,76)', 'rgb(255,0,0)', 'rgb(0,255,0)', 'rgb(255,255,0)', 'rgb(70,130,180)', 'rgb(255,0,255)', 'rgb(0,255,255)', 'rgb(255,255,255)']"
  ```
- **Rxvt**

  ```
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/$profile/palette "['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgb(205,0,0)', 'rgb(0,205,0)', 'rgb(205,205,0)', 'rgb(0,0,205)', 'rgb(205,0,205)', 'rgb(0,205,205)', 'rgb(250,235,215)', 'rgb(64,64,64)', 'rgb(255,0,0)', 'rgb(0,255,0)', 'rgb(255,255,0)', 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(255,0,255)', 'rgb(0,255,255)', 'rgb(255,255,255)']"
  ```
- **Default**

  (same as Tango but with different palette color 1 -- dark grey instead of black)

  ```
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/$profile/palette "['rgb(46,52,54)', 'rgb(204,0,0)', 'rgb(78,154,6)', 'rgb(196,160,0)', 'rgb(52,101,164)', 'rgb(117,80,123)', 'rgb(6,152,154)', 'rgb(211,215,207)', 'rgb(85,87,83)', 'rgb(239,41,41)', 'rgb(138,226,52)', 'rgb(252,233,79)', 'rgb(114,159,207)', 'rgb(173,127,168)', 'rgb(52,226,226)', 'rgb(238,238,236)']"
  ```

  or

  ```
    dconf reset /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/$profile/palette
  ```

<sup>With help from [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal#comment1132393_558308)</sup>

---

#### 14.04

In the below commands, replace `$profile` with your profile name, which you can get from

```
gconftool-2 --all-dirs /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles
```

It will usually be `Default`.

- **Tango**

  ```
    gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$profile/palette --type=string "#000000000000:#CCCC00000000:#4E4E9A9A0606:#C4C4A0A00000:#34346565A4A4:#757550507B7B:#060698209A9A:#D3D3D7D7CFCF:#555557575353:#EFEF29292929:#8A8AE2E23434:#FCFCE9E94F4F:#72729F9FCFCF:#ADAD7F7FA8A8:#3434E2E2E2E2:#EEEEEEEEECEC"
  ```
- **Linux console**

  ```
    gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$profile/palette --type=string "#000000000000:#AAAA00000000:#0000AAAA0000:#AAAA55550000:#00000000AAAA:#AAAA0000AAAA:#0000AAAAAAAA:#AAAAAAAAAAAA:#555555555555:#FFFF55555555:#5555FFFF5555:#FFFFFFFF5555:#55555555FFFF:#FFFF5555FFFF:#5555FFFFFFFF:#FFFFFFFFFFFF"
  ```
- **XTerm**

  ```
    gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$profile/palette --type=string "#000000000000:#CDCB00000000:#0000CDCB0000:#CDCBCDCB0000:#1E1A908FFFFF:#CDCB0000CDCB:#0000CDCBCDCB:#E5E2E5E2E5E2:#4CCC4CCC4CCC:#FFFF00000000:#0000FFFF0000:#FFFFFFFF0000:#46458281B4AE:#FFFF0000FFFF:#0000FFFFFFFF:#FFFFFFFFFFFF"
  ```
- **Rxvt**

  ```
    gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$profile/palette --type=string "#000000000000:#CDCD00000000:#0000CDCD0000:#CDCDCDCD0000:#00000000CDCD:#CDCD0000CDCD:#0000CDCDCDCD:#FAFAEBEBD7D7:#404040404040:#FFFF00000000:#0000FFFF0000:#FFFFFFFF0000:#00000000FFFF:#FFFF0000FFFF:#0000FFFFFFFF:#FFFFFFFFFFFF"
  ```
- **Default**

  (same as Tango but with different palette color 1 -- dark grey instead of black)

  ```
    gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$profile/palette --type=string "#2E2E34343636:#CCCC00000000:#4E4E9A9A0606:#C4C4A0A00000:#34346565A4A4:#757550507B7B:#060698209A9A:#D3D3D7D7CFCF:#555557575353:#EFEF29292929:#8A8AE2E23434:#FCFCE9E94F4F:#72729F9FCFCF:#ADAD7F7FA8A8:#3434E2E2E2E2:#EEEEEEEEECEC"
  ```

  or

  ```
    gconftool-2 --unset /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$profile/palette
  ```

<sup>With help from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/732083)</sup>

---

By the way, doing this via GUI is easy:

1. Open `gnome-terminal`
2. Go to **Edit** → **Profile preferences** → **Colors** → **Palette**
3. Change the **Built-in scheme**

Comment: Just to emphasize: the color "scheme" (e.g. "rxvt") is not stored in the settings, it's the 16 individual colors that are stored. The color "scheme" is only a concept of the graphical profile editor.

Comment: @youtubefreak With 16.04 you'll need `gsettings` or `dconf` (with similar but different command line syntax than `gconftool-2`).

Comment: using `dconf` didn't work for me... but `gsettings` did work. This was on `GNOME Shell 3.18.5` and `GNOME Terminal 3.18.3`. For example: `_profile="$(dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/default | tr -d "'")"`, and then `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${_profile}/ palette "['rgb(0,0,0)', ... etc ... 'rgb(238,238,236)']"`